# Execution order with try-finally in python generator functions

Tags: python, generator, try-finally

```
def gen():
    try:
        yield 1
    finally:
        print("finally")


def main():
    print(next(gen()))
```

This code prints

```
finally
1
```

I don't understand the order of execution here. Why is "finally" printed before "1"?

Comment: Because `finally` block triggered on leaving `try` and value returned from generator function on leaving function.

Comment: You'd see the same with `return 1`

Comment: Yes @olvin, that's it. A subtle point about garbage collection. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the line `print(next(gen()))` as

```py
g = gen()  # temporary variable
val = next(g)
#          # the generator is now deleted because the variable g is not referenced anymore
del(g)     # that calls the "finally" block `print("finally")`
print(val)
```

If you assign the generator to a variable, but don't delete it then it is recycled at the end of main function. That is what you probably expect.

A generator should be assigned to a variable if you use it by `next()`, otherwise there would be no way to use a generator with more items because it would be recycled after the first item!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why "finally" is printed before "1" is because the first thing Python does is resolve `next(gen())`, which involves returning 1 and printing "finally". Once Python is done executing `next(gen())`, it has printed finally, and has a value of 1. Now, it can resolve `print(1)`, which prints "1".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example what is happening

1. next(gen()) is executed -> gen()  prints "finally" -> next() gets the value
2. next() returns the value
3. print() prints the value

You have to look here inside first and then the outer shell and the outer outer shell etc.